# Android: In the fragment class, on accessing a variable of Activity class through it's getter method, the variable's value remains 0

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

Activity class has a integer in the onCreate method, which is set through getIntent.

```
    pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
```

-1 is the default value for getIntExtra(), "position" is the key where I'm storing it in another class. This value should be dynamic for clicks, and it is.
However, on accessing it in the fragment class through activity's getpos() method, it always returns 0.
Why?

This is the Acitivity class's OnCreate Method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);}
```

This is the Acitivity class's getter Method for pos:

```
public int get(){
        return pos;
    }
```

This is the Fragment's onCreateView method:

```
//an inflater
    Activity my=(Activity) getActivity();
    int posfrag = my.get();
```

I'm trying to access Recycler View's item positions through this, however the posfrag here doesn't get updated in fragment although, pos is correctly updated in the Activity method. The problem is in passing that retained value to the fragment.

Comment: Can you show more code? I'm having a hard time picturing what you're trying to do and what you're doing.

Comment: Share more chunks of code

Comment: Sorry, updated my question

Comment: What is this "position" variable which you return from the `get` function? Isn't the variable called "pos"?

Comment: Yes, it's the same one @Bal0r

Comment: Add logging. Make sure that the `Activity.get()` method is actually called. Log what the value is of `pos` that is being returned. Or use a debugger and set breakpoints and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the pos value in onActivityCreated() method inside your Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // retrieve your variable value here
}
```